# .NET Core - Problems with a partial class for a dbcontext broker implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been following Hassan Habib's excellent Youtube tutorials on API creating using his Open Schools application. I believe he has an excellent structure for an API. I decided to try it for myself and have run into a rather baffling problem.

He constructs the `dbContext` - `StorageBroker` out of multiple partial classes.

In his base `StorageBroker` class his constructor is as follows.

```
public partial class StorageBroker : EFxceptionsIdentityContext<User, Role, Guid>, IStorageBroker
{
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public StorageBroker(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.Database.Migrate();
        }
}
```

So a constructor with a single argument. He then constructs all the various table brokers as partial classes. That's logical. Here is the contacts partial class:

```
public partial class StorageBroker
{
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

        public async ValueTask<Contact> InsertContactAsync(Contact contact)
        {
            var broker = new StorageBroker(this.configuration);
            EntityEntry<Contact> contactEntityEntry = await broker.Contacts.AddAsync(entity: contact);
            await broker.SaveChangesAsync();

            return contactEntityEntry.Entity;
        }

        public IQueryable<Contact> SelectAllContacts() => Contacts;

        public async ValueTask<Contact> SelectContactByIdAsync(Guid contactId)
        {
            var broker = new StorageBroker(this.configuration);
            broker.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

            return await broker.Contacts.FindAsync(contactId);
        }

        public async ValueTask<Contact> UpdateContactAsync(Contact contact)
        {
            var broker = new StorageBroker(this.configuration);
            EntityEntry<Contact> contactEntityEntry = broker.Contacts.Update(entity: contact);
            await broker.SaveChangesAsync();

            return contactEntityEntry.Entity;
        }

        public async ValueTask<Contact> DeleteContactAsync(Contact contact)
        {
            var broker = new StorageBroker(this.configuration);
            EntityEntry<Contact> contactEntityEntry = broker.Contacts.Remove(entity: contact);
            await broker.SaveChangesAsync();

            return contactEntityEntry.Entity;
        }
}
```

That's fine however when I did it in my .NET Core application I am getting an error on the following line of code:

```
var broker = new StorageBroker(this.configuration);
```

Here is the error:

> 'StorageBroker' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

I have both partial classes identical yet I am getting this error. I note - as above - that the main partial class containing the constructor does indeed have one argument.

Just for the sake of being complete here is the OnConfiguring method:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    string connectionString = this.configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
}
```

Given I have re-created the same code, just in another solution, surely it should recognise the constructor with one argument.. the only constructor..

Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is causing an error. Hopefully something simple. I am rusty.

Comment: Ok, what tutorial did you follow? If it suggested this literal code, it's not a good tutorial. Why are you creating a new `StorageBroker` within each (non static) method of `StorageBroker`? What are you trying to achieve and why? Now strange things are happening, like re-checking is all database migrations have been applied on each small update.

Comment: I even see this `EFxceptions` has had it's last big upgrade 3 years ago and is just supporting some exceptions... are you sure you want to use that? Rather you not first learn the basics of [Entity Framework (Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)?

Comment: The tutorial is by Hassan Habib. You can look him up on github. I got the impression he knew what he was doing.. As for migrations that can be changed later I think. As it stands I am wondering why his code passes and this doesn't. I am thinking it most likely be a simple issue..

Comment: The repo is OtripleS. Cheers.

Comment: Why is the class even split up into two partial classes? Just merge the files and the problem is gone. But I concur with previous comments. The code is smelly. Also because (1) `StorageBroker` is a context class while its name doesn't show that and (2) A context class shouldn't have such specific CUD methods; it violates the *separation of concerns* principle.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your partial classes are in the same namespace. If they are in different namespaces and you include the namespace for the partial class that does not have the constructor defined, you will get the behavior you are describing.